# Grails disable view generation of a domain class variable

Tags: grails, gsp

I am working on a multi-tenant architecture based plugin, where I am adding a `tenantId` variable on few domain classes. Now this variable gets assigned its value automatically at object creation time via some code in Domain class itself and the User need not assign it manually.

Now the problem is that I need to provide this functionality to other developers and who actually generate the GSP views using `grails generate-views com.something.someClass`.

By doing this the generated view also has field for selection of `tenant`. So is there any domain class constraint or any setting that I can apply to prevent this variable from being automatically included in the view?

P.S. - Any such setting will be anytime better than manual removal of field from view each time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try follow steps:

1- run this command to copies the the templates used by Grails during code generation

```
grails install-templates
```

2- then open `_form` file (found in `src/templates/scaffolding` folder)

3- add `tenantId` in `excludedProps` variable like grails did with `version` field

```
excludedProps = Event.allEvents.toList() << 'version' << ... << 'tenantId'
```

Note- I haven't tried this.